# Открытие продолжения статьи на новой странице с кастомной ссылкой

Tags: url, php, mysql

На начальной странице есть статьи, не полные и внизу ссылка "Читать дальше". Сейчас при нажатии на "Читать дальше" у меня переходит на страницу "read_more.php" и там уже из БД берутся все элементы той записи и отображаются. **НО** дело в том, что всегда открывается на той странице, read_more.php.

Вопрос: Как сделать, чтобы при нажатии на Читать дальше открывалась страница наподобие `"blog.com/" + $row['link']`

где row['link'] содержит строку, которую я сам ввел в БД, допустим "hello-world". Тогда чтобы при нажатии я перешел на страницу blog.com/hello-world.php

Буду рад вашей помощи!

Comment: Mod_Rewrite вам в помощь...
Либо делайте полноценный роутинг со своими правилами.

Comment: а подсказать как сделать можете? Я уже 4-й день вокруг хожу. Подтолкните хотя бы

Comment: @navi1893 писать много текста не буду, дам ссылку на статейку, там и демо есть код, так что будет над чем подумать.

статья http://www.itlessons.info/php/routing-library/

Comment: @navi1893, я писал в прошлом ответе про фронт контроллер и роутер

Comment: оу, уведомление не приходило, вот и не увидел. Прочту обязательно! Спасибо!